# Linear transformation and minimal polynomial

Tags: finite-groups, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

A linear transformation $T: \Bbb Z_p \times \Bbb Z_p \to  \Bbb Z_p \times \Bbb Z_p $, where $p$ is a prime, is defined by $T(v)=s^{-1}vs$. The minimal polynomial is $m(x)=x^2+x+1$. Also $u=T(t)=s^{-1}ts$. Then $\{t,u\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb Z_p \times \Bbb Z_p$. Then can we say $T(t^i u^j)= t^{-j} u^{i-j}$?

Please help me with this question.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Use curly brackets "{,}" and the superscript  will apply to everything inside the curly bracket.

Comment: may be this is a silly question but from where to where the linear transformation is? You have written $T: Z_p\times Z_p$ and it does not make any sense to me

Comment: Sorry. I edited it correctly now. Please help.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this question?

Comment: You need to be clear what set $s$ comes from and whether you really meant to write $T(v)=s^{-1}vs$ rather than, say, $T(v)=s^Ts^{-1}v$

Comment: $s$ comes from $Z_3$. Actually there is a Semi direct product between  $Z_3$ and  $Z_p \times Z_p$, where $Z_p \times Z_p$ is the normal subgroup. The above linear transformation represents the action of $s$ on $Z_p \times Z_p$ which is actually conjugation (in Semidirect product). And order of $s$ is 3 and order of $t$ is p. Also {s,t} is a minimal generating set for the semidirect product.

Comment: Could you explain all the symbols used _precisely_ and _in the question_. Otherwise I'm afraid this will have to be closed as "unclear what you are asking".